# Disable automatic calculation for Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

is it possible to specify to Google spreadsheet not to recalculate a specific sheet or number of cell everytime a modification is done ?
I have a very heavy sheet and it's very slow everytime i made a tiny modification, even if it's in an another sheet.

Answer (score 10):

Seems that this feature is not supported by Google Spreadsheets. From a cursory search online the easiest way to work around this limitation is to make your formulas all conditional on a trigger. ie `=IF(Boolean_Trigger,Your_formula,"")`. Trigger could be a cell, Named range, etc. Regards,

Comment: Thanks for the great idea, @nbayly, this solved a similar problem I had!

Comment: @CamilleRethoret if this answer helped you, don't forget to check to accept it.

Comment: 7 years later and this answer is still the best solution I've come across.